# Program not finishing after trapping Cancel event

Tags: c#, event-handling, task, cancellation

Why does this console app not exit when Ctrl+C is pressed?

program output:

```
Press Ctrl+C to stop...
doing stuff.
doing stuff.
...
*Ctrl+C pressed*
exiting...
*never actually exits*
```

---

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args) {

        MyAsyncClass myAsync = new MyAsyncClass();

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) => { tcs.SetResult(null); };

        var task = Task.Run(() => myAsync.Start());

        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Press Ctrl+C to stop...");

        await tcs.Task;
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("exiting...");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyAsyncClass {
    public async Task Start() {
        while(true) {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("doing stuff.");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't it more like ctrl-D ?

Comment: No, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `Task.Run` is invoking asynchronous code without awaiting it.

Comment: Even if I completely comment out the while loop it still hangs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `ConsoleCancelEventArgs.Cancel` property to `true`:

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) =>
{
    tcs.SetResult(null);
    e.Cancel = true;   // <-------- add this to your code
};
```

This will allow your code to continue to the end of the program and exit normally, rather than the `Ctrl+C` to try to terminate the application after the event handler is done.

Note that in testing, I found that this only seems to matter when the Visual Studio debugger is attached (running with `F5`).  But running without one attached (`Ctrl+F5`, or just running the compiled .exe) didn't seem to care if this property was set or not.  I could not locate any information that explains why this is the case, but my guess is that there's some sort of race condition going on.

Lastly, it would be good form to pass a `CancellationToken` into your `myAsync.Start` method and use it instead of `while(true)`.  It would also be better to use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` (but neither of these is the source of the problem).

Comment: Downvoter - please explain.  This indeed solved the issue both in replicating the issue and in the OP's original problem.

Comment: Exactly what I encounter and deduced. Too bad I didn't find your answer before it would have save me some time. Additionally, it wasn't just running without debugging it also using windows cmd, terminate without finishing (not graceful), that led me to think I'm missing something in the cancel event. Anyway, I'm upvoting so other people will see it as well and I will try editing the question.